# Trigger only one command in a nested group

Tags: python, discord.py

So I was coding a discord bot and my friend told me I could put a group inside of another group, so I tried it out like so:

```py
@bot.group(aliases=['dono'])
async def donation(ctx):
    """Adds/subtracts to someone's total donation in a server (must be done by a mod)."""

@donation.group(aliases=['lb'])
async def leaderboard(ctx):
    """Shows the leaderboard for the users who donated the most."""
    [some long boring code that has no errors, that essentially just sends a leaderboard on who has donated the most]
        
@leaderboard.command(aliases=['gaw', 'ga'])
async def giveaway(ctx):
    """Shows the leaderboard for the users who donated the most to giveaways."""
    [some more perfectly fine but boring code that shows who has donated the most to giveaways]
```

However, (assuming my prefix is '!') when I do "!dono lb gaw", it runs both the leaderboard and the giveaway leaderboard command. So I came up with two solutions but couldn't find anything online. One was to delete all the code inside the leaderboard command, and then somehow if there was a way to make an empty command where if you just typed '!dono lb' it would show up, or if I could somehow put in like the parameters or something to make it only do one of them? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `invoke_without_subcommand=True` in the group decorator

`@bot.group(aliases=['dono'], invoke_without_subcommand=True)`

Comment: Thanks for telling me about this! It didn't work, but after doing some research on it I found that if I did `@donation.group(aliases=['lb'], invoke_without_command=True)`